# Binarize data across multiple columns

Tags: r, for-loop, case

Hi I have dataframe and in 13 columns of my df values are coded from 1 to 5. I want to replace 1,2 with 0 and 3,4 with 1 and drop 5. How I can make a change in my current data without mutating? Because there are 13 columns needed to be changed

Comment: `mutate` would still be my way to go with conjunction of `across` https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html

Comment: `data >= 3` converts a data frame `data` to binary.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have this stimulated dataframe:

```
set.seed(123)

df <- matrix(rep(sample(1:5, 5*13, replace = T)), ncol = 13) %>% as.data.frame()

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13
1  2  1  5  5  5  4  5  3  1   1   1   2   4
2  4  3  3  2  4  3  5  4  3   2   3   1   1
3  3  5  4  1  4  3  4  2  3   3   4   4   2
4  5  3  3  2  5  2  4  2  2   2   1   5   2
5  5  3  1  5  4  1  1  2  1   5   3   2   5
```

#### Base R

We can first set `df == 5` to `NA`, and use a logical expression to see if values are greater then or equal to 3 (proposed by @danlooo in the comment).

The `+(df >= 3)` syntax is used to convert logical output of `df >= 3` to integer.

```
df[df == 5] <- NA
df <- as.data.frame(+(df >= 3))
```

#### dplyr

Or we can use the `mutate` with `across` combination in the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~case_when(.x %in% 1:2 ~ 0, 
                                                    .x %in% 3:4 ~ 1, 
                                                    TRUE ~ NA_real_)))
```

#### Output

```
df
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13
1  0  0 NA NA NA  1 NA  1  0   0   0   0   1
2  1  1  1  0  1  1 NA  1  1   0   1   0   0
3  1 NA  1  0  1  1  1  0  1   1   1   1   0
4 NA  1  1  0 NA  0  1  0  0   0   0  NA   0
5 NA  1  0 NA  1  0  0  0  0  NA   1   0  NA
```

#### Data

Here's the `dput(df)` for easier data loading.

```
structure(list(V1 = c(2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L), V2 = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 3L), V3 = c(5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L), V4 = c(5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L
), V5 = c(5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L), V6 = c(4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L), V7 = c(5L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 1L), V8 = c(3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L), V9 = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 1L), V10 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L), V11 = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
3L), V12 = c(2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L), V13 = c(4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Coercion using `+` is obscure and, even to experts, the intent is non-obvious. Please don’t write code like that; do it properly, i..e either leave it as a logical (generally the preferred way!), or use `ifelse` or `as.integer` for the conversion if an integer is really necessary.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you for your feedback! May I ask whether `as.data.frame(df >= 3) + 0` or `0 + (df <= 3)` is acceptable to turn a logical matrix to an integer dataframe?

Comment: I don’t think that’s any different from using the prefix `+`. Both hide the *intent* of the code behind a side-effect (implicit coercion) of an ostensibly unrelated operation (addition). Ideally code should show explicitly *what is intended*. We don’t intend to perform addition here, we intend to perform coercion. That’s `as.integer`, not `+`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below (borrow data from [@benson23](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71868575/12158757), thanks!)

```
> df[] <- (df >= 3) * NA^(df == 5)

> df
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13
1  1 NA NA  0  0  1  0 NA NA   0   0   0  NA
2  1  1  1  0  0 NA  0 NA NA   0   0   0  NA
3  0  0  1 NA  1  1  0  1  1   1   1   0   1
4  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0 NA   0   1   0   0
5  1  1  1  0  0 NA  1  0  0  NA   1   1   1
```

- `df >=3` yields boolean matrix consisting of `TRUE` or `FALSE`
- `NA^(df == 5)` yields a matrix consisting of `NA` or `1`, since `NA^0 = 1` and `1^NA = NA`, and this matrix will play as a mask
- The element-wise product between two matrix retains the non-`NA` entries and also turns boolean values to numerics

Comment: Clever. But do *you* want to maintain code written like this?!

Comment: @KonradRudolph I added some explanations, do you mean that?

Comment: Hmm well in general you’d prefer code that didn’t require external explanation; i.e. that’s (as much as possible) self-explanatory.

Comment: data[18:28] <- (data[18:28] >= 3) * NA^(data[18:28] == 5) I wanted to apply this but gave everything zero. 18:28 is columns I want to change

Comment: I want to number 1 and 2 with 0 and 3,4 with 1

Comment: @NebiRehimov You should use `data[18:28,]`

Answer (score 1):

I would either perform the conversion as a two-step process (since there are two rules), or write a function that encapsulates your rules, and apply those. I’ll be using ‘dplyr’ `mutate` in the following since that seems to be what you’re using:

Here’s the two-step process:

```
df |>
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(.x, .x == 5L, NA))) |>
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ .x >= 3L))
```

And here it is using a function:

```
myrule = function (x) {
    if_else(x == 5L, NA, x >= 3L)
}

df |> mutate(across(everything(), myrule))
```

Here it is crucial that you give the function `myrule` a descriptive name that fits your problem domain.